# vim: how to copy a word in vim visual mode, but paste it in visual block mode?

Tags: linux, vim

I want to copy a simple text using visual mode of vim, but then paste it into multiple lines using block mode. How can I achieve this.

example:

```
//this all lines are commented for debug -- 
int c = 10;
int a = 2;
uint8 d = 0;
uint8 n = 0;
```

I want to acheive:

```
//this all lines are commented for debug -- 
//this all lines are commented for debug -- int c = 10;
//this all lines are commented for debug -- int a = 2;
//this all lines are commented for debug -- uint8 d = 0;
uint8 n = 0;
```

I tried by highlighting the comment section (using v right_arrow combination), and yanked . Now I want this yanked result to be pasted infront of all intended lines. This need not be at beginning of the line, 
I cant use I option to manually type the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would yank the first line, then go in block visual mode on the first column `<C-V>` and select several lines, `I`nsert before, and paste the default register from insert mode (`<c-r>"`). In other words:

```
y$<down><home><c-v>4<down>I<c-r>"<esc>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of ,<c-r>" trick. 
This will be helpful in other places too.

Comment: Have a look at `i_CTRL-R` documentation. `"` isn't the only register available. Often I use `.` in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the minimum (starting with the cursor in first row and first column, where you can get by <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>):
<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>CTRL-v</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>. (Tested with Vim 8.2, launched with `vim -u NONE` to be sure my setting don't affect the test.)

Given the title of the question, I don't think you need any explanation, except that <kbd>P</kbd>, if you are in visual block mode, pastes on all the lines you've selected.

[Luc Hermitte's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60873214/5825294), however, shows a powerful trick (<kbd>CTRL-r</kbd>) which can be useful in a much wider variety of situations.

Comment: This do not work, When I paste (P), it only pastes to the first line in block visual mode.
Even if I press (Esc), only first line got the update.

Comment: @ranjithkonaje, the fact that you say that the line gets updated when you hit Escape makes me think you are using a different command which enters insert mode. My command never enters insert mode. Please review my answer (I have removed a superflous keystroke, btw) and make sure you are pressing those 3 keys to get at the position (1,1) and those 7 keys to do the job.

Comment: python conv.py K:\VECTORS\
a
b
`code` c
`code` d
`code` e
`code` f
`code` g
`code` h

suppose this was my code, 
when I executed your sequence:
I got:
`code` python conv.py K:\VECTORS\
`code` python conv.py K:\VECTORS\
`code` 
`code` 
`code` d
`code` e
`code` f
`code` g
`code` h

Comment: the above comment do not look visually clear - I could not format it correctly, 
but the result is Only on 2nd line python conv K:\VECTORS\ got added

Comment: @ranjithkonaje you have never mentioned anything like `K:\VECTORS\`. Please, update the question with formatted code, and specify what you want to do and what you have tried.

Comment: I tried the same without formatted text, still same result, it is updating only the first line of visual block selection.
what is your     set ve=?

Comment: @ranjithkonaje, it is empty for me, the default. Please, try my solution when opening vim with `vim -u NONE yourfile`.

Comment: I tried - with -u NONE yourfile --> still no luck. It pastes only to first line,aswell it deletes the first character of all the line (they are selected under visual block, when we do ctrl-v 2 j

Comment: I don't know what to suggest anymore. If you want to show me what happens, you can make a terminal recording using [`asciinema`](https://asciinema.org/).

Comment: I dont have enough permission in my linux system to add/install. How can I paste a image in comment section?

Comment: @ranjithkonaje a static image would be of no help, imho. You can install stuff in your home, you don't need to install it systemwise. Furthermore, you can make a video and upload it somewhere, in nothing else works. Have you tried the other answer, btw?

Comment: @ranjithkonaje, you could also give some more detail on your vim version and OS you are using.